# FindBy avoiding full xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Having the following WebElements defined in my class

```
 @FindBy(xpath = ".//div[contains(@id, 'myform')]")
 private WebElement form;

 @FindBy(xpath = ".//div[contains(@id, 'myform')]"+ "/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/input[contains(@id, 'name')]")
 private  WebElement name;
```

i am able to locate and do a sendKeys on the name WebElement.
However this "/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/" doesn't look nice. How can i avoid it and still be able to locate my element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
.//div[contains(@id, 'myform')]//fieldset//input[contains(@id, 'name')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `id` of that element then you can directly locate that element using it e.g.-

```
@FindBy(id= "name")
```

Although you can try using `xpath` in these way too -

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@id, 'name')]")
```

or

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@id, 'myform')]//input[contains(@id, 'name')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ID if it is available. So, using id the declaration would be:

```
@FindBy(id = "name");
```

But if you like to use x-path then try it in the shortest form:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id ='name']");
```